# Export Applet Java with referenced libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, export

I have coded an applet requiring 1 library jar file (prowser-0.2.0). I have tested it on eclipse (3.6) and it works but when i put it on my html website, i have got the following error. I have impoted pbrowser library from project properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add external Jar.
This code works in runnable jar and as applet in Eclipse.

Error from Java Console :

> "Exception in thread "thread applet-myapplet.class-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.zenkey.net.prowser.Prowser
>       at myapplet.init(myapplet.java:8)
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"

Applet code :

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import com.zenkey.net.prowser.*;
public class myapplet extends Applet {

public void init() {

    Prowser prowser = new Prowser();
    Tab tab = prowser.createTab();
    System.out.println(tab.go("http://www.google.com").getPageSource());    

   }
}
```

Html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title> hello world </title>
</head>

<body>
This is the applet:<P>
<applet code="myapplet.class" archive="hello.jar,prowser-0.2.0.jar" width="150" height="50">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Really Thanks for help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are hello.jar and prowser-0.2.0.jar in the same directory as the HTML file in your web server that serves the HTML? The applet seems to find hello.jar as your error message indicates. The prowser-0.2.0.jar needs to be added to the same directory as a separate file, *not* being packed inside hello.jar itself (as Eclipse allows you to do if you select "export as runnable jar").

Then I'd also check the manifest file of hello.jar to see whether it contains unusual `Class-Path` entries for the prowser Jar. It should not contain any relative or absolute path information, just the file name itself.

Comment: yes hello.jar and prowser library are in the same directory as the html file. I haven't export it as runable jar but as jar file, i have just add prowser library as external jar library file in the Java build Path in Eclipse.

Comment: I edited the post, you could also check the Jar's manifest file.

Comment: the manifest file : 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: prowser-0.2.0.jar

Comment: Beats me then, I'm sorry. Is Javascript an option for you? Then you could try [deploying using a JNLP file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have solved my problem, i have imported directly source from the library in my project but now i have got a return "null" as response but when i execute it on eclipse i have the correct response. I will create another thread for this issue.

Comment: `prowser-0.2.0.jar` should it be mentioned in classpath of manifest file inside `helloworld.jar`?